# Typescript How to merge two types

Tags: typescript

How can I merge these two types into a single type?
The first one is for a form and the second one is for an async function. The only difference is that second one returns a Promise

```
export interface RegisterFormType {
  fullname: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  tel: string;
  address: string;
  status: string;
  category: string;
  service?: string;
}

export type RegisterPropsType = (
  fullname: string,
  email: string,
  password: string,
  tel: string,
  address: string,
  status: string,
  category: string,
  service?: string
) => Promise<any>;
```

Comment: You can merge two types with a union (with an `|`, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#unions) or an intersection (with an `&`, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#intersections) depending on whether you want to merge them or just use one of them.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no relation between property names and function parameter names in types.  Function parameter names are *placeholders* and can be changed without affecting types.  On the other hand, object property ordering is arbitrary and can be changed without affecting types.  The only way you could get close to what you want is to spell out both the order of the properties and the names of the function parameters, with some wordy and redundant mapping.  See [here](https://tsplay.dev/WJRORW).  It's basically not possible.

Comment: The simplest solution here would be to change `RegisterPropsType` to `(form: RegisterFormType) => Promise<any>` and change callers to use object literals. Having that many function parameters is bad practice and will only get worse when adding more properties.

Comment: I agree with @Clashsoft.  Even if there *were* a plausible way to convert from `RegisterFormType` to `RegisterPropsType` programmatically, it's much simpler just to use a single object as the parameter instead of a list whose order might be confusing without significant IDE assistance.